# 140: invalid card owner, Mercado pago, Asociar tarjeta a

Tags: mercadopago

Este es mi codigo

```
public function create_card($id, $token)
    {
        $request = array(
                            "uri" => "/v1/customers/{$id}/cards",
                            "data" => array(
                                  "token"=>$token
                                            ),
                            "params" => array(
                                "access_token" => $this->get_access_token())

                        );

        $customer = MPRestClient::post($request);
        return $customer;
    }
```

pero al final cuando trato de asociar la tarjeta me sale este error: 140: invalid card owner,

Claro yo ya capture el token de tarjeta y ya cree el customer, lo que necesito es simplemente asociar la tarjeta al customer

Comment: Tengo exactamente el mismo problema, incluso utilicé los datos reales de tarjeta. No puedo seguir y no brindan ninguna respuesta

Comment: Una pregunta, en que estas realizando el llamado tal vez estas usando laravel?

Comment: Esto sucede tambien si tenes varios applications en mercadopago. Como cada application tiene sus propias credenciales, los toma como "cuentas separadas" (vaults separados). Cada application guarda los customers, y cards de forma independiente, alternar credenciales devolveria el mismo error.

Answer (score -2):

la Respuesta era muy sencilla, en el caso mio la aplicación estaba hecha en laravel.... por lo tanto las claves de acceso estaban en el archivo .env
el token, client_id y client_secret.
Pero estaba yo realizando pruebas con otra cuenta tambien. el punto es que estaba grabando los customers y cards_token con otra cuenta y claro cuando la iva a asociar me decia que no era propietario de la tarjeta... así que muchachos revisen que su client_id, client_secret, public_key y token_accesss de mercado pago sean los correctos a la la hora de realizar estas acciones en el api de mercadopago